# How to apply firebase storage rule so only Google cloud run API can write?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

My goal is to block any write requests that don't come directly from my API in google cloud run.

I think my firebase Web API key from the general project settings could help but I can't find the right storage rule that can do this.

I found the storage rule for authenicated users etc but I don't use firebase authentication. Instead I authenticate users in the API that is hosted in google cloud run.

I think it is in this direction but please correct me if I am wrong.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request comes from my API with the Web API key;
    }
  }
}
```

sources:

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to check what API key is used in the call to Cloud Storage.

But access from Cloud Run usually happens through one of the GCP SDKs/APIs and those access the project with administrative privileges and bypass your security rules altogether.

So you might as well deny all write access from untrusted clients with:

```
allow write: if false;
```